# JwtBearer middleware with ES256 always 401 Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

Tags: jwt, bearer-token, asp.net-authorization

token is created using

```
 public class AppTokenHandler : TokenValidator, IAppTokenHandler
    {
        private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler _handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        private readonly AppTokenConfiguration _appTokenConfiguration;
        private readonly RsaSecurityKey _publicKey;
        private readonly ECDsa _key;

        public AppTokenHandler(IOptions<AppTokenConfiguration> appTokenConfiguration, RsaSecurityKey publicKey, ECDsa key)
        {
            _appTokenConfiguration = appTokenConfiguration.Value;
            _publicKey = publicKey;
            _key = key;
        }

        public string Create(Dictionary<string, object> claims)
        {
            var name = claims["name"].ToString();

            ////create token security key used to sign token from app's rsa private key
            //using var rsa = RSA.Create();
            //var rsaKey = _appTokenConfiguration.RsaKey;
            //rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(rsaKey), out _);
            //RsaSecurityKey rsaSecurityKey = new(rsa);

            ////create signing credentials, specifying not to cache signature provider
            //SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new(rsaSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
            //{
            //    CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory { CacheSignatureProviders = false }
            //};

            SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new(new ECDsaSecurityKey(_key), SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256);

            // create token
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Audience = _appTokenConfiguration.Audience,
                Claims = claims,
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2),
                IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Issuer = _appTokenConfiguration.Issuer,
                SigningCredentials = signingCredentials,
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, name),
                })
            };

            var encodedJwt = _handler.CreateEncodedJwt(tokenDescriptor);

            return encodedJwt;
        }

        public override bool Validate(string tokenString, out JwtSecurityToken token, out SecurityTokenValidationException validationException)
        {
            validationException = null;
            token = null;

            var publicKey = ECDsa.Create(_key.ExportParameters(false));

            var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // validate lifetime
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                // validate audience
                RequireAudience = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = _appTokenConfiguration.Audience,
                // validate issuer
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = _appTokenConfiguration.Issuer,
                // set source of name
                NameClaimType = "name",
                // validate signing key
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                //IssuerSigningKey = _publicKey
                IssuerSigningKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(publicKey)
            };
            
            try
            {
                var validate = _handler.ValidateToken(tokenString, validationParameters, out var validatedSecurityToken);
                token = _handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenString);
            }
            catch (SecurityTokenValidationException ex)
            {
                validationException = ex;
                return false;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, object> MapClaims(JwtSecurityToken accessToken, JwtSecurityToken idToken)
        {
            List<string> claimKeys = new()
            {
                "name",
                "preferred_username",
                "oid",
                "tid",
                "azp",
                "family_name",
                "given_name",
                "email"
            };

            var claims = accessToken?
                .Claims
                .Where(x=>claimKeys.Contains(x.Type))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Type, x => x.Value as object)
                ??
                new Dictionary<string, object>();

            var idTokenClaims = idToken
                .Claims
                .Where(x => claimKeys.Contains(x.Type))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Type, x => x.Value as object);

            foreach (var claim in idTokenClaims.Where(x => !claims.ContainsKey(x.Key)))
                claims.Add(claim.Key, claim.Value);

            claims.Add("scp", "app_authorized_user");

            return claims;
        }

    }
```

token is configured using

```
public class AppTokenOptions
    {
        public static Action<JwtBearerOptions> ConfigureToken(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            return options =>
            {
                var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                var authConfig = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppTokenConfiguration>>();
                var publicKey = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RsaSecurityKey>();
                var privkey = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ECDsa>();
                //var key = ECDsa.Create(privkey.ExportParameters(false));
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {

                    // validate lifetime
                    RequireExpirationTime = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    // validate audience
                    RequireAudience = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = authConfig.Value.Audience,
                    // validate issuer
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = authConfig.Value.Issuer,
                    // set source of name
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    // validate signing key
                    RequireSignedTokens = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    //IssuerSigningKey = publicKey
                    IssuerSigningKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(ECDsa.Create(privkey.ExportParameters(false)))

                };

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();

                options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    (context.Principal?.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)?.AddClaim(new Claim("cpcb", "test"));
                };

            };
        }
    }
```

auth is added immediately in ConfigureServices of Startup.cs using

```
 public static class AuthServicesRegistration
    {
        public static IServiceCollection ConfigureApplicationAuthServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            // get relevant config sections
            IConfiguration appAuth= Configuration.GetSection("Auth:app");
            IConfiguration aadIdTokenAuth = Configuration.GetSection("Auth:AADIdToken");

            // create keys for app token
            using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(3072))
            {
                string rsaKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey());
                string rsaPublicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey());

                appAuth["RsaKey"] = rsaKey;
                appAuth["RsaPublicKey"] = rsaPublicKey;
            }

            // bind auth configs
            services.Configure<AppTokenConfiguration>(appAuth);
            services.Configure<AzureAdIdTokenConfiguration>(aadIdTokenAuth);

            // add public key instance as singleton
            // so it can be used in .net's token validation middleware
            // otherwise if just declared when defined token validation parameters
            // the RSA instance will be prematurely disposed and you will get misleading 401s
            services.AddSingleton(provider => {

                RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
                rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(Convert.FromBase64String(appAuth["RsaPublicKey"]), out _);
                return new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
            });

            services.AddSingleton(provider =>
            {
                return ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);
            });

            // add provider for microsoft openidconnect config
            services.AddSingleton<IOpenIdConnectConfigurationProvider>(provider =>
            {
                var stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                var configProvider = new OpenIdConnectConfigurationProvider(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
                configProvider.AutomaticRefreshInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                return configProvider;
            });

            // add authentication schemes
            // default is app token
            services.AddAuthentication("app")
                .AddJwtBearer("app", AppTokenOptions.ConfigureToken(services))
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "Auth:AzureAd", "aad");
            
            // configure aad token options
            services.Configure("aad", AzureAdTokenOptions.ConfigureAadToken());

            // add authorization
            services.AddAuthorization();

            // add auth related services
            services.AddScoped<IAppTokenHandler, AppTokenHandler>();
            services.AddScoped<ITokenValidator, MicrosoftIdTokenValidator>();

            return services;
        }

    }
```

token generation endpoint and test endpoint to validate token

```
 [ApiController]
    [Route("api/auth")]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly IAppTokenHandler _appTokenHandler;
        private readonly ITokenValidator _idTokenValidator;

        public AuthController(IAppTokenHandler tokenHandler, ITokenValidator idTokenValidator) : base()
        {
            _appTokenHandler = tokenHandler;
            _idTokenValidator = idTokenValidator;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns token for requested resource verifying using msal accesstoken
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "aad")]
        [RequiredScope(AcceptedScope = new[] { "app_login" })]
        [Route("token")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> token()
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.TryGetValue("identity", out var idTokenString)) return Unauthorized("No identity present to verify");

            var aadToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("aad", "access_token");
            
            JwtSecurityToken accessToken = null;
            if (aadToken != null)
            {
                accessToken = new JwtSecurityToken(aadToken);
            }
            
            // verify idToken
            if (!_idTokenValidator.Validate(idTokenString, out var idToken, out var validationException))
            {
                return Unauthorized($"invalid id token: {validationException.Message}");
            }
            
            // get / verify user

            // get claims from tokens
            var claims = _appTokenHandler.MapClaims(accessToken, idToken);

            // generate token
            var encodedJwt = _appTokenHandler.Create(claims);

            return Ok(encodedJwt);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Test authorize endpoint
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Authorize]
        [RequiredScope(AcceptedScope = new[] { "app_authorized_user" })]
        [Route("validate/{token}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> validate(string token)
        {
            var authorization = Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString().Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
            try
            { // both validate calls are successful when authorize attribute is commented out
                if (_appTokenHandler.Validate(token, out _, out var ex))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("valid token");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("invalid token", ex.Message);
                }

                if (_appTokenHandler.Validate(authorization, out _, out var ex2))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("valid auth header");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("invalid auth header", ex2.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            }

            return Ok(token);
        }

    }
```

if i swap out ES256 for RSA I had previously wired up, no issues. However, when I tried swapping out RSA for ES256, I got the error "The signature key was not found". If I remove the authorize attribute on the validate endpoint, get a token from the token endpoint and then verify the token using the app token handler, it's valid. There seems to be an issue with the jwt bearer middleware?? I have tried using the full ECDsa instead of just the public key, a singleton of an ECDsaSecurityKey with a key id and without a key id, a singleton of a jsonwebkey, and now a singleton of just the ecdsa. All same result. app token handler instance validates it with same token validation parameters, but jwt bearer middleware fails authorization. And again, if I swap out the signing credentials to use the RSA credentials, everything works just fine.

1. Am I creating the signing keys incorrectly?
2. Am I providing the public / private keys incorrectly to jwt bearer middleware?
3. Am I missing something in token creation?
4. How do I hook into jwt bearer middleware to get a better idea of what is going on? I see there is the ontokenvalidated event but that is not being hit obviously, is there an event I can hook into that might provide more info into what is going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the ecdsa instance used to create private key was getting displosed too early (?)

Ended up creating the ecdsa and saving the ecparams to config (similar as with rsa keys), created singleton of ecdsasecuritykey with just q and curve (so just public key), used serviceprovider to get ecdsasecuritykey to set as issuersigningkey for token validation in configure jwtbeareroptions, then used all ecparams from config (bound in apptokenconfiguration class) to create private key ecdsasecuritykey when creating the token

in configureapplicationauthservices

```
// create keys for app tokens
        using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(3072))
        using (ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256))
        {
            // rsa
            string rsaKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey());
            string rsaPublicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.ExportRSAPublicKey());

            appAuth["RsaKey"] = rsaKey;
            appAuth["RsaPublicKey"] = rsaPublicKey;
            appAuth["RsaKid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            
            // ecdsa
            ECParameters ecParams = ecdsa.ExportParameters(true);
            appAuth["D"] = Convert.ToBase64String(ecParams.D);
            appAuth["QX"] = Convert.ToBase64String(ecParams.Q.X);
            appAuth["QY"] = Convert.ToBase64String(ecParams.Q.Y);
            appAuth["EcKid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

 // bind auth configs
        services.Configure<AppTokenConfiguration>(appAuth);
        services.Configure<AzureAdIdTokenConfiguration>(aadIdTokenAuth);

        // add rsa public key instance as singleton
        // so it can be used in .net's token validation middleware
        // otherwise if just declared when defined token validation parameters
        // the RSA instance will be prematurely disposed and you will get misleading 401s
        services.AddSingleton(provider => {
            RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
            rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(Convert.FromBase64String(appAuth["RsaPublicKey"]), out _);
            return new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
        });

        // add ecdsa public key same way as rsa
        services.AddSingleton(provider =>
        {
            ECParameters ecParams = new ECParameters();
            ecParams.Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256;
            ecParams.Q = new ECPoint()
            {
                X = Convert.FromBase64String(appAuth["QX"]),
                Y = Convert.FromBase64String(appAuth["QY"])
            };
            ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ecParams);
            return new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa);
        });
```

token configuration for middleware

```
public static Action<JwtBearerOptions> ConfigureToken(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return options =>
        {
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            var authConfig = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppTokenConfiguration>>();
            var publicKey = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RsaSecurityKey>();
            var ecpublicKey = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ECDsaSecurityKey>();
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {

                // validate lifetime
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                // validate audience
                RequireAudience = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = authConfig.Value.Audience,
                // validate issuer
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = authConfig.Value.Issuer,
                // set source of name
                NameClaimType = "name",
                // validate signing key
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = ecpublicKey
                //IssuerSigningKey = publicKey
                
            };

            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();

            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                (context.Principal?.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)?.AddClaim(new Claim("cpcb", "test"));
            };

            options.Validate();

        };
    }
```

token creation (and validation for manual testing)

```
 public class AppTokenHandler : TokenValidator, IAppTokenHandler
    {
        //private readonly JsonWebTokenHandler _handler = new();
        private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler _handler = new();
        private readonly AppTokenConfiguration _appTokenConfiguration;
        private readonly RsaSecurityKey _publicKey;
        private readonly ECDsaSecurityKey _ecdsaPublicKey;

    public AppTokenHandler(IOptions<AppTokenConfiguration> appTokenConfiguration, RsaSecurityKey publicKey, ECDsaSecurityKey ecdsaPublicKey)
    {
        _appTokenConfiguration = appTokenConfiguration.Value;
        _publicKey = publicKey;
        _ecdsaPublicKey = ecdsaPublicKey;
    }

    public string Create(Dictionary<string, object> claims)
    {
        var name = claims["name"].ToString();

        //create token security key used to sign token from app's rsa private key
        //using var rsa = RSA.Create();
        //var rsaKey = _appTokenConfiguration.RsaKey;
        //rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(rsaKey), out _);
        //RsaSecurityKey rsaSecurityKey = new(rsa);

        ////create signing credentials, specifying not to cache signature provider
        //SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new(rsaSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
        //{
        //    CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory { CacheSignatureProviders = false }
        //};

        ECParameters ecParams = new ECParameters();
        ecParams.Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256;
        ecParams.D = Convert.FromBase64String(_appTokenConfiguration.D);
        ecParams.Q = new ECPoint()
        {
            X = Convert.FromBase64String(_appTokenConfiguration.QX),
            Y = Convert.FromBase64String(_appTokenConfiguration.QY)
        };
        using ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ecParams);
        ECDsaSecurityKey ecdsaSecurityKey = new(ecdsa);

        SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new(ecdsaSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256)
        {
            CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory { CacheSignatureProviders = false }
        };


        // create token
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Audience = _appTokenConfiguration.Audience,
            Claims = claims,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2),
            IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Issuer = _appTokenConfiguration.Issuer,
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, name),
            }),
            SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
        };

        var encodedJwt = _handler.CreateEncodedJwt(tokenDescriptor);
        return encodedJwt;
    }

    public override bool Validate(string tokenString, out JwtSecurityToken token, out SecurityTokenValidationException validationException)
    {
        validationException = null;
        token = null;

        var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // validate lifetime
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            // validate audience
            RequireAudience = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = _appTokenConfiguration.Audience,
            // validate issuer
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = _appTokenConfiguration.Issuer,
            // set source of name
            NameClaimType = "name",
            // validate signing key
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _ecdsaPublicKey
            //IssuerSigningKey = _publicKey
        };

        try
        {
            var validate = _handler.ValidateToken(tokenString, validationParameters, out var validatedSecurityToken);
            token = _handler.ReadJwtToken(tokenString);
        }
        catch (SecurityTokenValidationException ex)
        {
            validationException = ex;
            return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

gonna clean this up a bit, but at least it is working correctly now :)